# How to append address of current cell to range object

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to write a function that goes through an Excel worksheet to find a range of cells fulfilling a certain condition (two cells in the same row that have to be equal).

I've written the following code that goes through the Worksheet row by row and checks if the condition is fulfilled. 
If a cell is found for which the condition is true I would like the address of the cell to be added to a range. 
The output of the function should finally be this range which is subsequently used to populate a dropdown menu in a dialog with the entries fulfilling the condition.

```
Private Function DetermineRange(WorksheetName As String, Column1 As Integer, Column2 As Integer) As Range

    Dim rng As Range

    'Go through rows of specified worksheet
    For currRow = 1 To Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        'Compare cells in specified columns of current row
        If Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, Column1).Value = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, Column2).Value _
          And Not (Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, Column1).Value = "") Then

            'If cells are equal, but not empty, append current adress of current cell to range
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2))
            Else
                Set rng = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2)
            End If
        End If

    Next currRow

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'return found Range
        Set DetermineRange = rng
        MsgBox ("Range is: " & rng)
    Else
        'DEBUG: Throw error message if rng is empty,
        MsgBox ("DEBUG DetermineRange Function:" & vbCrLf & _
        "Error! No corresponding Cells found in Sheet" & WorksheetName)
    End If

End Function
```

Cycling through the rows works fine, however I don't seem to be able to add the addresses for the cells after the condition is checked to the range object. 
I have also tried the following, which results in a

> Runtime error 424: Object required

```
'If cells are equal, but not empty, append current address of current cell to range
 If Not rng Is Nothing Then
       Set rng = Union(rng, Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2).Address)
 Else
       Set rng = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2).Address
 End If
```

I've been looking around, but can't seem to find much information on how to add cells to range objects however...
Maybe one of you could help! Any kind of pointer in the right direction is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

**Edit:** 
I am calling the function like this:

```
Set NameRng = DetermineRange("Features", ProjectColumn, TCGroupColumn)
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & NameRng.Address
```

But I get the following error:

> Runtime Error 380: Not able to set property RowSource

Comment: You have a union of ranges, whereas Address is a property of a range which is a string so just drop it.

Comment: You mean just leave out the .Address ? 
That's what I've been trying in the first code snippet, but it doesn't yield the expected result!

Comment: Yes. In what way is it unexpected? Your function returns a range so you can then access its address property. You could make your function return a string of addresses instead.

Comment: I've tried checking the contents of the range object by outputting it through a msgbox, but it only displays the value of the first element of the object...
So maybe this is where I wrongly assumed it wasn't working properly!

Comment: However, I'm still not able to assign the range to the dropdown (see edit of the initial post)...

Comment: What is the name of "Worksheets(3)"? You might need `"'" & Worksheets(3).Name & "'!" & NameRng.Address`. Have you checked that the function is returning a range which is not nothing?

Comment: Btw would be easier if you used the Find method as you are replicating an existing function.

Comment: Thanks for all your Input @SJR. Looks like the function is actually working now. I'll start a new question concerning the assignment of the found range to the combobox RowSource which seems to be the culprit!
If you want to post the suggestion of the preexisting  Find method as an answer I'll accept it as the best answer! Thanks again for all your input!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but on reflection I'm not sure Find would be much better as you are comparing adjacent cells and would still need to loop through each row. Find is usually advantageous because you can avoid a loop.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to capture the cell addresses.  Concatenate these and use the final value to build a new range.

Example:

```
Public Function DetermineRange(WorksheetName As String, Column1 As Integer, Column2 As Integer) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim currRow As Integer
    Dim targetSheet As workSheet    ' Shortcut to requested sheet.
    Dim matchesFound As String      ' Address of matching cells.

    ' This line will raise an error if the name is not valid.
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName)

    'Go through rows of specified worksheet
    For currRow = 1 To targetSheet.UsedRange.Rows(targetSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'Compare cells in specified columns of current row
        If targetSheet.Cells(currRow, Column1).Value <> "" Then
            If targetSheet.Cells(currRow, Column1).Value = targetSheet.Cells(currRow, Column2).Value Then

                ' Capture address of matching cells.
                If Len(matchesFound) > 0 Then

                    matchesFound = matchesFound & "," & targetSheet.Cells(currRow, Column1).Address
                Else

                    matchesFound = targetSheet.Cells(currRow, Column1).Address
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next currRow

    ' DEBUG: Throw error message if no matches found.
    If Len(matchesFound) = 0 Then

        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 101, "DetermineRange", "No matching cells found."
    End If

    ' Return range.
    Set DetermineRange = targetSheet.Range(matchesFound)
End Function
```

The code is a little rough and ready.  I can't help but feel there are few too many lines.  But the basic approach works.